# What good tutorials you know about MySQL Stored Procedures?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to write a stored procedure to increment the value of an int column by one. Looks like a very simple task, but not for someone without ANY experience with stored procedures.

To do that I looked for tutorials and code samples, and found a few, but sure there are better ones out there. Do you know any?

The ones I found:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/call.html (code sample)
- http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/print.php/3525581
- http://www.mysql.com/news-and-events/newsletter/2004-01/a0000000297.html
- http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/A-DIY-Approach-to-Stored-Procedures-in-MySQL/
- http://www.phpbits.info/mysql-tutorial/stored-procedures-in-mysql/
- http://www.kbedell.com/2009/03/02/a-simple-example-of-a-mysql-stored-procedure-that-uses-a-cursor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in german but it is a good one.
http://www.tutorials.de/forum/sql-tutorials/179510-stored-procedures-mysql-5-a.html

In english I think the stuff at this place is fine. You got many different tutorials.
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend picking up a copy of [MySQL Second Edition by Larry Ullman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321375734).  He has a good overview of stored procedures.  That coupled with the tutorials you've already found should give you a good start with them.